# GoogleSpreadSheet timestamp when data is send from Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have built a website using Wordpress.

I have used CF7 Google sheet Connector as a plug-in to send the data from my website to my google-spreadsheet.

Here is my question.
I have 2 speadsheets, "Sheet Data" and "Sheet timestamp".

when a new data is send from website, the data is added on "Sheet Data".
In addition, when "Sheet Data" gets a new record, it also adds a part of data that is send from website to "Sheet Timestamp". Upon getting the data on "Sheet timestamp", I would like to have timestamp on the left side of spreadsheet.

I pasted my code below.

But right now, whenever I open the spreadsheet, it over-writes all the timestamp dates with a current date.

Add I also use `onEdit()` however, it seems like I am not editing a spreadsheet but I am send a data to spreadsheet. That's why it does not trigger the function.

```
function TIMESTAMP() {

  var today = new Date();

  var month = new Array();
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";
 
 var date = month[today.getMonth()]+' '+today.getDate()+', '+today.getFullYear();

 var dateTime = date;
 return dateTime;
 
}
```

```
function onEdit(e) {
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  //1.Change 'Sheet1' to be matching your sheet name
  if (r.getColumn() == 3 && ss.getName()=='DATA-Model') { // 2. If Edit is done in any column before Column (I)  And sheet name is Sheet1 then:
    var celladdress ='A'+ r.getRowIndex()
    ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
};
```

Please provide me a solution to this problem if you could.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: but how is timestamp connected with the onEdit function ?

Comment: I did not connect. there are just two separate functions that i have tested with.

Comment: How is the sheet timestamp getting the data? Maybe you can parse the data before getting into the sheet and add the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheet, just add a column `date` and `time`.

see the end of this article for full explanation : https://compile.blog/cf7-data-to-google-sheets/